# Google Maps SDK in iOS 8

Tags: ios, google-maps, sdk, ios8

When I load a map using the Google Maps SDK in iOS 7 the only code I need for displaying "My Location" is:

```
self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
```

When I load the code that I have in iOS 8 however, I am unable to get my location. Is there extra code that I need to include in order to make the my location portion of the SDK work in iOS 8?

Comment: @Paulw11 The Google Maps SDK does not require you to have any interaction with core location in iOS 7.

Comment: In order to find your location it uses Core Location "under the covers". In ios8 you need to add the entries to your info.plist and request appropriate permission